# default resource provider and SqlResourceProviderFactory in the same asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, resources

is it possible to use the default resource provider that uses .resx files in the application but uses an SqlResourceProvider in a sub folder?

seems like the only one used is the one configured in web.config of the root?

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something similar, returning a custom ResourceProvider for specific classkeys, but then fallback to default resource providers otherwise.

I created a custom ResourceProviderFactory that returns my custom resource provider when requested, but otherwise returns null, which appears to cause the default provider to be used instead.

```
[DesignTimeResourceProviderFactory(typeof(CustomizedResourceProviderDesignTimeFactory))]
public class CustomizedResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
    public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(string classKey)
    {
        if (classKey == "MyCustomResourceClass")
        {
            return new CustomizedResourceProvider(classKey);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: When I return null from this, I get a NullReferenceException within framework code :-(